# File(1) classifying null bytes as data file

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have some behaviour from the file commandline function. Seemingly it classifies null bytes as data files, even though to the best of my knowledge, and what i can find online null bytes are part of UTF-8. Below is an example of my problem.

`printf "Hello\00, World!" > test.txt
file test.txt
Output: test.txt: data`

Why isn't this classified as UTF-8?

Comment: Because a null byte is not a valid UTF-8 text character?

Comment: Why not? From my understanding of the utf-8 set null bytes are indeed part of utf-8
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3906755

Comment: The null byte indeed exists in UTF-8, but if cannot occur in a UTF-8 **text** file: it it neither a printable character nor a *normal* control (such as Carriage Return of Line Feed)

Answer (score 0):

It's getting classified as generic data because of the 0 byte, which is not something that shows up in normal human-readable text. And if you take that out, because all it has is printable ASCII characters, it'd get classified as that, not UTF-8.